# the axis in the apply method (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, apply, axis

This is a simple question, but felt like I needed to make sure.

```
df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Apparently, this code is supposed to execute the function row-wise for a given dataset. However, according to my knowledge, row-wise operations are done by axis = 0, not axis =1.

Could anyone tell me if the apply method somehow operates differently and I just need to know that this is an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

axis = 0 means the functions works along the column and axis = 1 means the functions works on the rows. For example

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
data.sum(axis = 0)
```

The result is

```
0    4
1    6
```

which is sum along the column